# Android monitor: when i try to take a screenshot i receive Screenshot Unsupported protocol: 2

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, huawei-mobile-services, android-device-monitor

With my huawei honor 10 (android 8.1) when I try from the android device monitor to take a screenshot I have this error :

> [2018-09-18 08:44:24 - Screenshot] Unsupported protocol: 2

What it's mean ? How can I take screenshot from android device monitor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you resolved this issue. For who are seeking an answer. Should update to the lastest SDK tool version on android sdk manager.